# Definition of zoom levels used by Cesium quantized mesh terrain tiles?

Tags: wgs84, cesium, 3d-tiles, quantized-mesh

## Context

I am not able to figure out the definition of [Cesium](https://cesium.com/)'s quantized mesh terrain tiles, as specified here:
https://github.com/CesiumGS/quantized-mesh

I wonder if it's the same definition (or not) than, for example, the one used by;

- [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/);
  https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels
- and also defined by the TMS specifications;
  https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification
- and the OGC "*OpenGIS Web Map Tile Service Implementation Standard*"; https://www.ogc.org/standards/wmts
  at page 105, "*Table E.4 —Definition of Well-known scale set GoogleMapsCompatible*"
- and also by [maptiler](https://www.maptiler.com):
  https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

I guess yes, but it's only a guess and I want to be 100% sure.

## Question

Where can I find their definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should definitely stop searching for specific keywords (i.e. 'zoom' & 'level') and read through all the specification carefully because it's written in this way;

> By default, the data is tiled according to the [Tile Map Service (TMS)](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification)
> layout and global-geodetic system. These defaults can be varied by
> specifying the projection and scheme.

Source: https://github.com/CesiumGS/quantized-mesh

That's clear enough for me.
I hope it will help.